# GAE NDB restore fails with "Unexpected error contacting datastore"

Tags: google-app-engine, backup, google-cloud-datastore

I'm used to performing regular backup and restore of my NDB datastore, often restoring to a different 'project', where I will be testing a new version of the application.   Up to now, it has worked fine.

Now, Ndb restore operation fails in a systematic way, with the trace in the log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/_internal/mapreduce/handlers.py", line 526, in handle
    ctx.flush()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/_internal/mapreduce/context.py", line 455, in flush
    pool.flush()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/datastore_admin/utils.py", line 695, in flush
    datastore._GetConnection()._reserve_keys(self.keys)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 2170, in _reserve_keys
    self._async_reserve_keys(None, keys).get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 921, in get_result
    results = self.__rpcs[0].get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 613, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 2211, in __reserve_keys_hook
    self.check_rpc_success(rpc)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1371, in check_rpc_success
    raise _ToDatastoreError(err)
InternalError: Unexpected error contacting datastore (2016-11-19T18:01:37+00:00).
```

Any clue ?  I may have missed something, but I would swear nothing has changed as compared to last week's situation where such restore worked ok.

Just in case there was something wrong with my latest backup, I tried to restore an old backup, which had been successfully restored a couple of times.  Same InternalError on restore.   Including in a brand new GAE project.

Having tried many (many) times now, I found the 'unexpected errors' always happen for the same entities.  The whole backup/restore involves about 30 different kinds, of which 5 fail with said error.   Among these, in some cases there are entities that are restored, but not all, in other cases no entities have been restored.   It's like some specific entities could be responsible for the exception.   But, once again, this also happens for old backups, which had worked in the past.

There are few questions related to Ndb backup and restore (and fewer answers still).   Don't Ndb applications use backups ?

Comment: The datastore is the same regardless of how you access it (ndb, db, other languages) so maybe you can try to restore without using ndb?  I backup/restore using the Datastore Admin tool which doesn't depend on ndb.

Comment: I am using the datastore admin tool as well, specifying a google storage bucket.   And yet I get messages in the log on /_ah/mapreduce/controller_callback/ and /_ah/mapreduce/worker_callback/.   This is where I got the trace that is copied.   Since I am still investigating, I will edit the question to add some precisions.

Comment: @patb I have experienced the same issue with my restore job yesterday. Never completed. While plenty of the mapreduce tasks did run successfully, there was one that kept throwing this error for many hours. Couldn't neither abort job (although abortion was confirmed in the UI). Had to delete it manually with all related _AE* records. Now in my second attempt, I had the same issue. Task queue is now empty (maybe that task hit the retry limit). Yet the job is marked incomplete. I suspect, this is a recent bug in the datastore admin restore functionality.

Comment: @ani, Thanks, interresting to know there are two of us experiencing the same thing.   I reported the bug in GAE issue tracker under #13414  https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13414

Comment: @ani, Are you also restoring to a different project than the one you performed the backup on?

Comment: I'm also having this issue when trying to restore from another project. Created a new case with cloud services support, I'll leave a comment if I can get it resolved with their help.

Comment: There are a number of us then.  The Google project team is working on the issue.  They have 'changed some settings' on the project, and asked me to retry, and the restore worked !   But then I tried on another project, and problem remained.  So the settings that fixed our issue would need to be applied on a per-project basis ?   Will keep you updated here.

Comment: We're working on a fix for this issue. In the interim, we'll be applying the setting patb@ mentions to projects that have encountered this error. If restores still fail, please file an issue here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list.

Comment: @patb Yes, I'm restoring from another project (from live project to staging)

Comment: This should now be fixed for all projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the final word on this is not hidden at the bottom of a long list of comments, I'll post an answer.

It seems this was a bug that had appeared a few days/weeks back, which a few users like me have experienced when restoring to another project.

The Google project team did a great job, fixing the issue promptly.   Many thanks to @Ed Davisson.